# set video as SET WALLPAPER in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i want to set video as Wallpaper just like ZEDGE Wallpaper and others wallpaper application do in play store. following is screen shot of ZEDGE Wallpaper app that set video As a Wallpaper in android.
[image]

i use below code for image as wallpaper:

```
  val intentt = Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA)
                    .setDataAndType(uri, "image/*")
                    .putExtra("mimeType", "image/*")
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)


            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intentt, getString(R.string.setas)), 1)
```

what can i do for Video to Set As Wallpaper?

Comment: the above code is for image to set as wallpaper. what will i do to set Video as wallpaper

Comment: it Say "not supported"

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html

Comment: this one is for images. not for video

Comment: I want to set image as wallpaper too, I use your code for my project, but "No apps can perform this action." I think the ```Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA)``` is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello i found solution for my problem:

in Kotlin Android:

```
    class VideoLiveWallpaperService : WallpaperService() {

    override fun onCreateEngine(): WallpaperService.Engine {
        return VideoEngine()
    }

    internal inner class VideoEngine : WallpaperService.Engine() {

        private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
        private val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer

        init {
            Log.i(TAG, "( VideoEngine )")
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(baseContext, R.raw.video1)
            mediaPlayer.isLooping = true
        }

        override fun onSurfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceCreated")
            mediaPlayer.setSurface(holder.surface)
            mediaPlayer.start()
        }

        override fun onSurfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
            Log.i(TAG, "( INativeWallpaperEngine ): onSurfaceDestroyed")
            playheadTime = mediaPlayer.currentPosition
            mediaPlayer.reset()
            mediaPlayer.release()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        protected var playheadTime = 0
    }

}
```

in Java:

```
public class VideoWallpaperService extends WallpaperService
{
    protected static int                playheadTime = 0;

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine()
        {
            return new VideoEngine();
        }

    class VideoEngine extends Engine
        {

            private final String        TAG     = getClass().getSimpleName();
            private final MediaPlayer   mediaPlayer;
            public VideoEngine()
                {
                    super();
                    Log.i( TAG, "( VideoEngine )");
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.wallpapervideo);
                    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceCreated( SurfaceHolder holder )
                {
                    Log.i( TAG, "onSurfaceCreated" );
                    mediaPlayer.setSurface(holder.getSurface());
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceDestroyed( SurfaceHolder holder )
                {
                    Log.i( TAG, "( INativeWallpaperEngine ): onSurfaceDestroyed" );
                    playheadTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
    }
```

}

in Manifest:

```
<service android:name=".VideoLiveWallpaperService"
        android:label="Video live wallpaper" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
        android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
</service>
```

in res/xml/wallpaper.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: Nice & polyglot, but a battery hungry application. Accept your own answer, so others may skip visiting.

Comment: i cannot today. because Stackoverflow accept answer on own questions 2 days later. so it will take time. thanks

Comment: Nice answer! You should fix the minor formatting issues for your code examples though (like using correct indenting all over the place)!